# Binding not updating as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a pre-loader screen that essentially says "please wait" as I have server-side computation being processed for several seconds.

I have a value converter that `should` update and get rid of the loader screen once the server-side computation has been processed and stored.

## WPF Portion

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Client:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="loadConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
.
.
.
    <Border Panel.ZIndex="1000" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="{Binding OverlayVisibility, Converter={StaticResource loadConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="#80000000" Margin="0,0,0,-25.6">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Panel.ZIndex="100" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Loading Passive Seismic Nodes..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="21" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFF"/>
            <TextBlock Panel.ZIndex="100" Margin="11,136,12,75.2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please Wait..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFF"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border
```

I have an `OverlayVisibility` property in this class that is a boolean value to help toggle the preloader screen.

## Portion of the Client Class

```
    public void LoadRoles()
    {
        foreach (var roleName in ChefServer.GetCookbookNames())
        {
            Cookbooks.Add(new Cookbook() { CookbookName = roleName });
        }
        //This isn't making the preloader disappear
        uiContext.Send((_ => { overlayVisibility = false; }), null);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!"); //This gets called successfully
    }
   
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }


    //This function gets called when WPF form loads
    public void Loader()
    {
        
        uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current; //Declared at top in namespace
        OverlayVisibility = true; //Make preloader screen show at boot
    }


    #region Props
    private bool overlayVisibility;
    public bool OverlayVisibility
    {
        get { return overlayVisibility; }
        set
        {
            overlayVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OverlayVisibility");
        }
    }
#endregion
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `overlayVisibility` (the field), not `OverlayVisibility` (the property).

Therefore, you never actually raise `PropertyChanged`, and WPF never finds out.

Comment: Are you referring to uiContext.Send((_ => { overlayVisibility = false; }), null); ? I changed this to OverlayVisibility and have the same issue.

Comment: During my debug, I see that BoolToVisibilityConverter never gets called..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have set up DataContext correctly? try adding the following line to your c'tor if you have not set it up yet

```
this.DataContext = this;
```